# How to return values from a nested Axios call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios, next.js

I am trying to perform the below steps:

**Step 1:** Make Axios call to check if record exists in database.
**Step 2:** If the record does not exit then make a POST API call to create data and return POST response.
**Step 3:** If the record already exists then return the response from Step 1

Step 1 and Step 2 works fine and I am able to return the value from `createProfileByUserIDNew`. When code block for Step 3 gets executed then `createProfileByUserIDNew` is not returning any value.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
async createProfileByUserIDNew(data, email) {
        const AuthStr = 'Bearer ' + getToken();
        const response = await axios
            .get(`${baseUrl}/buyer-profiles?user_email=${email}`, {
                headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
            })
            .then((response) => {

                 //*****This block return proper value in the next then
                if (response.data.length === 0) {
                    return axios.post(`${baseUrl}/buyer-profiles`, data, {
                        headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
                    });
                //~~~~~~~This block return proper value in the next then

                //*****This block does not return any value in the next then
                } else {
                    return response //Return response from first axios call
                }
                //*****This block does not return any value in the next then

            })
            .then((response) => {           
                return (response);  //Step 2 return the value but step 3 return undefined             
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)));
}
```

Calling the above method:

```
const ret = createProfileByUserIDNew(
    data,
    user.email
);
ret.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response); //Setp 2 returns proper value but step 3 return undefined
    this.setState({ buyerProfileId: response.items.id });
});
```

Comment: You should review this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/67648397#67648397

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because when you simply do `return response` you're returning the response of the request, not a `Promise`. You should only chain the `.then()` when making the `axios.post()` call since that actually returns a `Promise`.

Also, if you want to use the `createProfileByUserIDNew` function the way you are currently you need to return the `Promise` from `axios.get` directly.

```js
async createProfileByUserIDNew(data, email) {
    const AuthStr = 'Bearer ' + getToken();
    return axios.get(`${baseUrl}/buyer-profiles?user_email=${email}`, {
            headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
        })
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.data.length === 0) {
                return axios.post(`${baseUrl}/buyer-profiles`, data, {
                        headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
                    })
                    .then((response) => {           
                        return response;
                    });
            } else {
                return response;
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that async/await is "syntactic sugar" for the other promise syntax of chaining .then(), .catch(), and .finally(); in other words, it allows you to handle these types of asynchronous operations in code that appears more synchronous.

```
const createProfileByUserIDNew = async (data, email) => {
  const AuthStr = "Bearer " + getToken();

  try {
    // we're awaiting this response, so we don't need to chain a .then()
    // we could even destructure response into the objects we'll need later, 
    // i.e. const { data } = await axios.get(...)
    const response = await axios.get(
      `${baseUrl}/buyer-profiles?user_email=${email}`,
      {
        headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
      }
    );
    if (response.data.length === 0) {
      // do the things we need to do when we don't get the data we want
      // once again, we don't have to chain a then() to this; you may
      // have heard that 'return await' is redundant and causes some 
      // problems, but since we're in a try/catch it's ok
      // see https://jakearchibald.com/2017/await-vs-return-vs-return-await/
      return await axios.post(`${baseUrl}/buyer-profiles`, data, {
        headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
      });
    } else {
      // the user exists, so we'll do other things, like maybe return the 
      // original response or something
      return response;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("We hit a snag:", error);
  }
};

// now when we call this method (must be called from another async function), the same principles apply
const ret = await createProfileByUserIDNew(data, user.email);
console.log(ret);
This.setState({ buyerProfileId: ret.data.items.id });
```

Comment: @Sona Shetty it should be mentioned that this probably needs some tweaking, especially around the way you handle errors (because you've got two promises in your async function that could reject); hopefully this will set you on the right path!